# MVC web.config compilation debug=true - a manual change needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, web-deployment

When one creates a MVC project using the the built-in templates (File -> new Project etc) the web.config reads

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Inside the Web.Release.config I see this transform

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

so I was assuming that when I build in Release mode the debug="true" would disappear. However I am not seeing this.
Is the transform only applied when *publishing* the website? I've seen websites deployed by drag & drop, with the Web.config copied over from the root (with debug="true" included).

I'd just like to check, if deploying via drag & drop do you have to remove this attribute manually? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" attribute specifies that you want the debug attribute to be removed from the system.web/compilation element in the deployed  Web.config file. This will be done every time you deploy a Release build.

Comment: answered your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferred would be to publish your web-site (different to `F5` or `drag and drop`) so to update\transform the web.config ...

**Disable debug mode**

Depends on build configuration rather than destination environment, the debug attribute is for the Release build specifically when you typically want debugging disabled regardless of which environment you are deploying to.

Visual Studio project templates will create a Web.Release.config transform file with code that removes the debug attribute from the compilation element.

Below the default Web.Release.config: (with some sample transformation code that is commented out, it includes code in the  compilation element that removes the debug attribute:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value     of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial     Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so by using drag and drop you will have to edit config manually.

Comment: Edit your answer to put your comment about drag & drop scenario in (which was the question) and mention that the preferred way is via the publish option, which applies the transform to the config , and I'll mark it as the answer.